# Question about pdftexmagfix.tex

Tags: plain-tex

My setup: TL2014

I understand what pdftexmagfix.tex is for, I only don't understand how it works:

If we change

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`P=12
  \catcode`T=12
  \lowercase{%
\endgroup
\def\ppdfconvert@truept#1PT{#1truept}%
  }%
```

to

```
\def\ppdfconvert@truept#1pt{#1truept}%
```

we get this error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \ppdfconvert@truept.
```

Why this error is produced and why to set `catcode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro is used in

```
\def\ppdfmag@fix#1{#1=\expandafter\ppdfconvert@truept\the#1\relax}
```

When `\the\pdfhorigin` is expanded, it returns something like `123.45pt` (or whatever), with all characters of category code 12 (this is what always happens with TeX operations that return strings, only spaces receive category code 10).

So the argument to `\ppdfconvert@truept` must be delimited by characters with category code 12, which is what the code above does, exploiting the fact that `\lowercase` never changes the category code, but only the character code.

Note that the assignments of category codes are undone by `\endgroup`, but only after `\lowercase` has performed its duty.

The alternative road

```
\begingroup
\edef\otherpt{%
  \endgroup\def\noexpand\ppdfconvert@truept##1\string p\string t}%
\otherpt{#1truept}
```

is much clumsier.

---

If you proceed your way, the macro `\ppdfconvert@truept` expects to be followed by arbitrary tokens until finding `pt`, both with category code 11, which it can't find until the first `\par` or end-of-file, so TeX stops with a `Runaway argument` or `File ended while scanning use of` error.

When a macro with delimited arguments is defined, the arguments should be followed by the exact sequence of tokens in the delimiter: both character code *and* category code are taken into account for character tokens; symbolic tokens (that is, control sequences) in the delimiter need not be defined, but names must match.